# Blocking stackexchange

Tags: linux, networking, domain, blocking, hosts-file

I want to block every website on the stackexchange network (as I often tend to waste a lot of time on those). How can I do it?

One solution is to obviously write all the sites' entries manually in the hosts file, but is there a better solution?

Note that just blocking on the regex `*.stackexchange.com` won't work as a lot of websites have unique names like `superuser` and `askubuntu`.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

**Edit:**

I've posted this question here not to learn self-control, but because I am genuinely curious about its technical feasibility.

**Please write the reason for the downvotes in the comments so that I can act on it!**

Comment: I feel I shouldnt answer this on principal

Comment: Are you saying that every last SE site is irresistible, and if you just block them all, you won't find other sites out there to satisfy your addiction?  I don't know, it sounds like an XY problem to me.  :-)

Comment: Maybe install one of those programs that blocks all but some sites for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Since you obviously asked this question under a pseudonym, kindly please post your real SE name and password. The problem will take care of itself in no time.

Comment: You could always just [delete all your accounts](http://superuser.com/help/deleting-account)

Comment: I see technical aspects of this question too but feel its more about learning self control. Heard yoga is a thing these days :)

Comment: Hello everyone! If I wanted to learn self-control, I wouldn't have posted this question here; I am rather curious about whether this is actually technically feasible or not. So, I kindly request you to refrain from personally attacking and judging my self-control ability instead of offering technical solutions to the problem. I am surprised to see such unprofessional behaviour on stackexchange.

Comment: Also, I request the downvoters to explain the reason for downvoting in the comments, so that I can improve the question, and maybe remove it if it's inappropriate for this site. Also, I cannot just delete all my accounts as I want to disable SE temporarily.

Comment: You're trying to solve a people problem with technology. Generally that does not work well.

Comment: @Bob I just wrote that I'm curious about the technical feasibility of the problem. Even if I learned to control my temptation, I'll still be very curious about it.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi, don't take the jesting personally.  Part of the site's model is keeping dry technical stuff fun.  You have to expect that asking how to block all SE sites on an SE site is going to attract some of that.  Regarding downvotes, some people may have taken the question as being intended as a joke rather than a serious question, just because of the context.  Others likely reacted to what Bob commented on.  But see, you did get a good technical answer.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi - You should never remove questions, even if they are closed and have received several down votes, the reason for that is simple.  If you ask questions, and it receives votes you don't agree with, removing the question prevents you from improving it.  Ask enough questions that are not accepted by the community and you will end up being unable to ask question without any way to improve the question that received those votes that cause the question ban.

Answer (score 8):

First, an aside, spending time here on stackexchange is hardly wasting time.  Either you are getting answers to questions you ask, or helping out a fellow user.  Neither educating yourself nor helping your fellow man/woman is considered time wasted by anyone I know.

Second, with a reputation of 121, I doubt you have spent a faction of the time on here as I have with a repuation of 5000 and counting.

Whois reveals this so block this range and you won't get it.  If your firewall supports CIDR notation a single line below will block it all.

```
NetRange:       151.101.0.0 - 151.101.255.255
CIDR:           151.101.0.0/16
```

Command to block access to this IP range:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d 151.101.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

You will have to save the iptables configuation, otherwise when you reboot it is lost.  I don't know if Ubuntu has an automatic facility for that.

```
iptables-save ><somewhere>/iptables.save
iptables-restore <<somewhere>/iptables.save
```

if using systemd create a file named iptables.service in
/etc/systemd/system/

```
[Unit]
Description=IPtables load rules
DefaultDependencies=no
After=ipset.service network-pre.target
Before=network-online.target network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=-/bin/echo 'Starting iptables'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables-restore <somewhere>/iptables.save
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/iptables-restore <somewhere>/iptables.save
ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/iptables -flush
RemainAfterExit=yes
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_RAW

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

then **systemctl enable iptables**

Comment: Even after executing `iptables -I INPUT 1 -d 151.101.0.0/16 -j DROP`, I am still able to access StackOverflow.

Comment: By wasting time, I meant checking out random questions from the *Hot Network Questions* feed without any intention of answering them. And I spend most of time on StackOverflow rather than SuperUser.

Comment: You probably need this also:  iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 151.101.0.0/16 -J DROP and change INPUT to OUTPUT, in the previous rule.

Comment: It's working with `OUTPUT`; the `FORWARD`one is redundant.

Comment: Also, can you please explain exactly how did you find the ip range `151.101.0.0/16`?

Comment: Execute the **whois** command.  whois stackexchange.com, and read the first few lines of the response.

Comment: If you had other computer behind a NAT then FORWARD would come into play.

Comment: I am getting [this output](http://pastebin.com/FpRH3amy) from the command `whois stackexchange.com`. Where is the IP address located in it?

Comment: SE actually uses CloudFlare. Unless they're getting dedicated IPs, you're likely also blocking many other sites...

Comment: @Bob actually, they [are using Fastly now](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/739966545477181440).

Comment: @NathanOsman Yea, I was told yesterday :P Does Fastly also share IPs between their clients?

Answer (score 0):

As a softer solution, that you can easily configure to block stackexchange sites only for a limited time, you may consider the Chrome extension [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en-US).